# Find all the fixed subfield of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{40})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

Given the polynomial $$p(x) = x^{8}+x^{7}+x^{6}+x^{5}+2x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$$

The task was to find the splitting field,a primitive element of the extension, the Galois group,including counting all the subgroup and the respective fixed field.

My effort : noticing that $$p(x) =\frac{x^{9}-1}{x-1}+x^{4} =\frac{(x^{5}-1)(x^{4}+1)}{x-1}$$

I was able to affirm that the splitting field of $p(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{5},\zeta_{8}) =\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{40})$.

Besides, knowing that $Q(\zeta_{m}) \cap Q(\zeta_{m}) = Q(\zeta_{gcd(m,n)})$,

I was able to affirm that the Galois group $$Gal(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}) \cong Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{5})/\mathbb{Q}) \times Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{8})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$$

With some patience, we discover that there are :

A single subgroup isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{2})^{3}$, six subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, four subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, seven subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, seven subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and two non-proper subgroups.

Since the group is abelian and I know three generators, I can state that three of those are $\phi,\psi,\sigma$,where : $$ \begin{cases} \phi : \zeta_{5} \longmapsto \zeta_{5}^{2} \\ \psi : \sqrt{2} \longmapsto -\sqrt{2} \\ \sigma : i \longmapsto -i \end{cases}$$

The question concerns the study of the fixed subfield.

I know (thanks to the fundamental theorem of Galois group) that for every subgroup of the Galois group $H$, $H$ is associated to a single fixed subfield,extension of $\mathbb{Q}$,which degree corresponds to the index of the subgroup, $[G:H]$,where $G = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{40})/\mathbb{Q})$.

I'm really struggling to find these fixed fields.

Sometimes product or sums easily work, but when the group is bigger, I don't know a general approach,or what to look for,since it seems difficult to me to find the extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and justify their diversity, other than quadratic, which diversity is easily justifiable. For example extensions of degree $8$ or $4$,which correspond to subgroups of order two or four, are the most problematic.

Any help,method or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: A help, or tip is that we have several exercises with solutions here about this topic, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555948/is-there-a-standard-way-to-find-the-subfields-of-bbbq-zeta-n-when-n-is), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469936/computing-subfields-of-q-zeta-12?rq=1), etc.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks, $x^{9}$ shouldn't be there, edited it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think I know general facts about Galois theory, and the questions you linked, maybe the first one could help me, but I should use a conjecture or Gaussian periods which are above my knowledge. May I ask why about the downvote? I'm just trying to understand the concept through the problem I asked.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just say that the problem has been solved for $\zeta_n$, for several particular $n$, e.g., $\zeta_{12}$ in the linked question. The answers there are really what you need to compare with your solution. There are several more interesting links, e.g., also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830747/did-i-do-this-galois-theory-problem-right-subfields-of-mathbbq-zeta-12), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692645/intermediate-fields-of-cyclotomic-field-mathbbq-zeta-8-dummit-foote-14?noredirect=1), ...

Comment: or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808934/number-of-fields-between-mathbbq-and-mathbbq-zeta-n/1808944#1808944), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389066/determine-tha-intermediate-fields-of-mathbbq-zeta-20?rq=1), etc.